# Question about expressing the answer of a first order separable differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following differential equation, and I have solved it like this:

$(x^2 + 2)y' = 4xy$

$\frac{dy}{dx} \times \frac{1}{y} = \frac{4}{x} + 2x $

$\int\frac{1}{y} dy = \int(\frac{4}{x} + 2x) dx$

$lny = 4lnx + x^2 + C_{0}$

$y = e^{4lnx + x^2 + C_{0}}$

$y = C_{1}x^4e^{x^2}$

Answer should be:

$y = c_{1}(x^2 + 2)^2$

How can $x^4e^{x^2}$ be expressed as $(x^2 + 2)^2$ ?

Answer (score 2):

HINT: it must be $$\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{4x}{x^2+2}dx$$